# Count elements of array matching condition in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm basically looking for the swift equivalent of the follow c++ code:

```
std::count_if(list.begin(), list.end(), [](int a){ return a % 2 == 0; }); // counts instances of even numbers in list
```

My problem isn't actually searching for even numbers, of course; simply the general case of counting instances matching a criterion.

I haven't seen a builtin, but would love to hear that I simply missed it.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Like this:

```
 let a: [Int] = ...
 let count = a.filter({ $0 % 2 == 0 }).count
```

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for. Will accept in ~9mins.

Comment: You can eliminate the parens around the closure to make it a trailing closure.

Comment: Also, this will have an O(n) space allocation, is there a one liner that maintains O(1) space?

Comment: @AidanGomez The author of this answer should put a `lazy` before `filter` which avoids `O(n)` space allocation

Comment: @AidanGomez if the answer is working, please accept the answer :)

Comment: @AidanGomez - see below for an answer that only uses reduce and runs through the array only once.

Answer (score 10):

An alternative to Aderstedt's version

```
let a = [ .... ]
let count = a.reduce(0){ 
    (count, element) in 
    return count + 1 - element % 2
}
```

My intuition says my way will be faster because it doesn't require the creation of a second array. However, you'd need to profile both methods to be sure.

**Edit**

Following MartinR's comment about generalisation of the function, here it is

```
extension SequenceType
{
    func countMatchingCondition(condition: (Self.Generator.Element) -> Bool) -> Int
    {
        return self.reduce(0, combine: { (count, e) in count + (condition(e) ? 1 : 0) })
    }
}

let a = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 12].countMatchingCondition { $0 % 2 == 0 }
print("\(a)") // Prints 3
```

Comment: @MartinR I originally wrote that line as `return count + element % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 0` as it happens, which is the same but avoids casting booleans to ints.

Comment: I have deleted my previous comment because I noticed that `Int(element % 2 == 0)` actually creates an  `NSNumber` object from the boolean. – What I wanted to say is that your solution wouldn't work with more general predicates.

Comment: This turned out to be the fastest solution in my simple test :)

Answer (score 8):

Default array:

```
let array: [Int] = [10, 10, 2, 10, 1, 2, 3]
```

1. [filter(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/3018365-filter) method

`let countOfTen = array.filter({ $0 == 10 }).count // 3`

2. [count(where:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126943-count) method

> Update: This Swift 5.0 feature was withdrawn in beta testing because it was causing performance issues for the type checker.

```
let countOfTen = array.count(where: { $0 == 10 }) // 3
```

Comment: Is `count(where:)` a real thing? It's not working for me in Swift 5, and the link you provided is a 404 (page not found).

Comment: Okay, looks like `count(where:)` was removed from Swift 5 at the last minute.  Hopefully it will reappear in a future version.

Comment: This Swift 5.0 feature was withdrawn in beta testing because it was causing performance issues for the type checker. Hopefully it will come back in time for Swift 5.1, perhaps with a new name to avoid problems. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/126/whats-new-in-swift-5-0

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Collection.lazy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/1641236-lazy) to have the simplicity of Aderstedt's Answer but with O(1) space.

```
let array = [1, 2, 3]
let count = array.lazy.filter({ $0 % 2 == 0 }).count
```

Answer (score 3):

The most compact reduce statement that will do this is:

```
let a = Array(1 ... 20)
let evencount = a.reduce(0) { $0 + ($1 % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 0) }
```

Reduce takes two variables: starts with 0 (var $0) then for every element in Array a (var $1) if the value is divisible by 2 with no remainder then add one to your count.

This is also efficient as it does not create an additional array unlike using a.filter(){}.count .

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this with reduce()

```
let a = Array(1 ... 20)
let evenCount = a.reduce(0) { (accumulator, value) -> Int in
    guard value % 2 == 0 else { return accumulator }
    return accumulator + 1
}
```

Almost everything you want to do with the `map()` and `filter` functions can actually be done with a `reduce` although it's not always the most readable.

Comment: If the last line was `return accumulator + 1` you wouldn't need to make it `var`

Comment: @JeremyP I'll need to read up on reduce but these seem like another nice option.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 or later:

```
public extension Sequence {
    func occurrences(where predicate: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Int {
        try reduce(0) { try predicate($1) ? $0 + 1 : $0 }
    }
}
```

---

```
public extension Sequence where Element: Equatable {
    func occurrences(of element: Element) -> Int {
        reduce(0) { element == $1 ? $0 + 1 : $0 }
    }
}
```

---

```
let multiplesOf2 = [1,2,3,4,4,5,4,5].occurrences{$0.isMultiple(of: 2)}  // 4
"abcdeabca".occurrences(of: "a")  // 3
```

---

```
extension BinaryInteger {
    var isOdd: Bool { !isMultiple(of: 2) }
    var isEven: Bool { isMultiple(of: 2) }
}
```

---

```
(-4).isOdd // false
(-3).isOdd // true
(-2).isOdd // false
(-1).isOdd // true
0.isOdd    // false
1.isOdd    // true
2.isOdd    // false
3.isOdd    // true
4.isOdd    // false

(-4).isEven // true
(-3).isEven // false
(-2).isEven // true
(-1).isEven // false
0.isEven    // true
1.isEven    // false
2.isEven    // true
3.isEven    // false
4.isEven    // true
```

---

```
let odds = [1,2,3,4,4,5,5,11].occurrences(where: \.isOdd) // 5
let evens = [1,2,3,4,4,5,5,11].occurrences(where: \.isEven) // 3
```